# Why can't I add edges to manim graph?

Tags: debugging, math, graph, edges, manim

What basically happens is that even adding a simple edge which I know can already be permitted since the nodes that connect it has already been created through `graph.animate.add_vertices()` the method still won't work. For instance initially I have vertex 1 (as shown below) with no edges whatsoever, then when I add vertices 2, and 3 for instance and add edges (1, 2) and (1, 3), it raises an error `Exception: Cannot position endpoints of closed loop`

Here is the code I wrote:

```
class Graph7(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        edges = []
        partitions = []
        c = 0
        layers = [5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]  # the number of neurons in each layer

        for n_nodes in layers:
            partitions.append(list(range(c + 1, c + n_nodes + 1)))
            c += n_nodes

        # create the edges of neural network
        for i, v in enumerate(layers[1:]):
                last = sum(layers[:i+1])
                for j in range(v):
                    for k in range(last - layers[i], last):
                        edges.append((k + 1, j + last + 1))

        # create the nodes of the neural network
        vertices = np.arange(1, sum(layers) + 1)
        print(vertices)
        print(edges)

        # note graph nodes start from 1 in this case
        # initially also our graph will just be a single node then
        # progress to add more nodes
        graph = Graph(
            [1],
            [],
            layout_scale=5,
            vertex_config={
                'fill_color': BLUE,
                'fill_opacity': 0,
                'radius': 0.2,
                'stroke_width': 5,
                'stroke_color': WHITE
            },
        )

        self.play(Create(graph))
        # add the rest of the vertices which are from 2 to 34
        self.play(graph.animate.add_vertices(*vertices[vertices > 1], vertex_config={
                'fill_color': BLUE,
                'fill_opacity': 0,
                'radius': 0.2,
                'stroke_width': 5,
                'stroke_color': WHITE
            }))
        self.play(graph.animate.add_edges((1, 2)))
        self.play(graph.animate.change_layout('partite', partitions=partitions, layout_scale=5))
        self.wait(1)
```

And here is the full error that is shown to me:

```
┌─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────┐
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\cli\render\co │
│ mmands.py:115 in render                                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│   112 │   │   │   try:                                                                           │
│   113 │   │   │   │   with tempconfig({}):                                                       │
│   114 │   │   │   │   │   scene = SceneClass()                                                   │
│ > 115 │   │   │   │   │   scene.render()                                                         │
│   116 │   │   │   except Exception:                                                              │
│   117 │   │   │   │   error_console.print_exception()                                            │
│   118 │   │   │   │   sys.exit(1)                                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\scene\scene.p │
│ y:223 in render                                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    220 │   │   """                                                                               │
│    221 │   │   self.setup()                                                                      │
│    222 │   │   try:                                                                              │
│ >  223 │   │   │   self.construct()                                                              │
│    224 │   │   except EndSceneEarlyException:                                                    │
│    225 │   │   │   pass                                                                          │
│    226 │   │   except RerunSceneException as e:                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ D:\Projects\To Github\project-alexander-animations\tutorial.py:931 in construct                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    928 │   │   │   │   'stroke_width': 5,                                                        │
│    929 │   │   │   │   'stroke_color': WHITE                                                     │
│    930 │   │   │   }))                                                                           │
│ >  931 │   │   self.play(graph.animate.add_edges((35, 26)))                                      │
│    932 │   │   self.play(graph.animate.change_layout('partite', partitions=partitions, layout_s  │
│    933 │   │   # # self.wait(1)                                                                  │
│    934                                                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\scene\scene.p │
│ y:1082 in play                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1079 │   │   │   return                                                                        │
│   1080 │   │                                                                                     │
│   1081 │   │   start_time = self.renderer.time                                                   │
│ > 1082 │   │   self.renderer.play(self, *args, **kwargs)                                         │
│   1083 │   │   run_time = self.renderer.time - start_time                                        │
│   1084 │   │   if subcaption:                                                                    │
│   1085 │   │   │   if subcaption_duration is None:                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\renderer\cair │
│ o_renderer.py:104 in play                                                                        │
│                                                                                                  │
│   101 │   │   │   # In this case, as there is only a wait, it will be the length of the wait.    │
│   102 │   │   │   self.freeze_current_frame(scene.duration)                                      │
│   103 │   │   else:                                                                              │
│ > 104 │   │   │   scene.play_internal()                                                          │
│   105 │   │   self.file_writer.end_animation(not self.skip_animations)                           │
│   106 │   │                                                                                      │
│   107 │   │   self.num_plays += 1                                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\scene\scene.p │
│ y:1253 in play_internal                                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1250 │   │   │   │   break                                                                     │
│   1251 │   │                                                                                     │
│   1252 │   │   for animation in self.animations:                                                 │
│ > 1253 │   │   │   animation.finish()                                                            │
│   1254 │   │   │   animation.clean_up_from_scene(self)                                           │
│   1255 │   │   if not self.renderer.skip_animations:                                             │
│   1256 │   │   │   self.update_mobjects(0)                                                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\animation\com │
│ position.py:97 in finish                                                                         │
│                                                                                                  │
│    94 │   │   for anim in self.animations:                                                       │
│    95 │   │   │   anim.finish()                                                                  │
│    96 │   │   if self.suspend_mobject_updating:                                                  │
│ >  97 │   │   │   self.group.resume_updating()                                                   │
│    98 │                                                                                          │
│    99 │   def clean_up_from_scene(self, scene: Scene) -> None:                                   │
│   100 │   │   self._on_finish(scene)                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\mobje │
│ ct.py:1114 in resume_updating                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1111 │   │   if recursive:                                                                     │
│   1112 │   │   │   for submob in self.submobjects:                                               │
│   1113 │   │   │   │   submob.resume_updating(recursive)                                         │
│ > 1114 │   │   self.update(dt=0, recursive=recursive)                                            │
│   1115 │   │   return self                                                                       │
│   1116 │                                                                                         │
│   1117 │   # Transforming operations                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\mobje │
│ ct.py:843 in update                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│    840 │   │   │   if "dt" in parameters:                                                        │
│    841 │   │   │   │   updater(self, dt)                                                         │
│    842 │   │   │   else:                                                                         │
│ >  843 │   │   │   │   updater(self)                                                             │
│    844 │   │   if recursive:                                                                     │
│    845 │   │   │   for submob in self.submobjects:                                               │
│    846 │   │   │   │   submob.update(dt, recursive)                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\graph │
│ .py:1287 in update_edges                                                                         │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1284 │   def update_edges(self, graph):                                                        │
│   1285 │   │   for (u, v), edge in graph.edges.items():                                          │
│   1286 │   │   │   # Undirected graph has a Line edge                                            │
│ > 1287 │   │   │   edge.put_start_and_end_on(graph[u].get_center(), graph[v].get_center())       │
│   1288 │                                                                                         │
│   1289 │   def __repr__(self: Graph) -> str:                                                     │
│   1290 │   │   return f"Undirected graph on {len(self.vertices)} vertices and {len(self.edges)}  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\geome │
│ try\line.py:146 in put_start_and_end_on                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│    143 │   │   │   self.start = start                                                            │
│    144 │   │   │   self.end = end                                                                │
│    145 │   │   │   self.generate_points()                                                        │
│ >  146 │   │   return super().put_start_and_end_on(start, end)                                   │
│    147 │                                                                                         │
│    148 │   def get_vector(self):                                                                 │
│    149 │   │   return self.get_end() - self.get_start()                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project-alexander-animations\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\mobje │
│ ct.py:1669 in put_start_and_end_on                                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1666 │   │   curr_start, curr_end = self.get_start_and_end()                                   │
│   1667 │   │   curr_vect = curr_end - curr_start                                                 │
│   1668 │   │   if np.all(curr_vect == 0):                                                        │
│ > 1669 │   │   │   raise Exception("Cannot position endpoints of closed loop")                   │
│   1670 │   │   target_vect = np.array(end) - np.array(start)                                     │
│   1671 │   │   axis = (                                                                          │
│   1672 │   │   │   normalize(np.cross(curr_vect, target_vect))                                   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Cannot position endpoints of closed loop
```